# Permissions conlict with openvpn and systemd on Arch

Tags: systemd, openvpn

Just installed openvpn on my VPS.

Starts flawlessly with

```
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf
```

But

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server
```

won't run. There's a conflict with systemd.

The logs:

```
Options error: --ca fails with '/etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt': Permission denied (errno=13)
Options error: --cert fails with '/etc/openvpn/server/server.crt': Permission denied (errno=13)
Options error: --key fails with '/etc/openvpn/server/server.key': Permission denied (errno=13)
Options error: Please correct these errors.
```

The systemd config:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service for %I
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/openvpn --status %t/openvpn-server/status-%i.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config %i.conf
User=openvpn
Group=network
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
KillMode=process
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My server folder with keys and certificates:

```
ls -la
total 36
drwxr-x--- 2 openvpn network 4096 Jan 11 00:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root    4096 Jan 11 00:02 ..
-rw------- 1 root    root    1184 Jan 10 23:26 ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     424 Jan 10 23:29 dh2048.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     618 Jan 11 16:07 server.conf
-rw------- 1 root    root    4586 Jan 10 23:28 server.crt
-rw------- 1 root    root    1704 Jan 10 23:27 server.key
-rw------- 1 root    root     636 Jan 10 23:43 ta.key
```

Is there a fault in permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The config files need to be owned by `openvpn`.**

Your systemd service definition says that `openvpn` needs to run as user `openvpn`, group `network`. However, when you run it using `sudo`, you're running it as user `root`.

All the files are owned by root and most of them mode 0600, thus not readable by anyone else. This needs fixing so that the `openvpn` user can read them.

Just run `chown openvpn:network /etc/openvpn/server/*`.

Comment: I also had the certs under my `/home/user/.openvpn/my-vpn` directory which was causing a file not found error so I had to move it to a custom `/etc/openvpn/certs/my-vpn/` and it it's all working now.